# jhbuild failed to build yelp-xsl for libxslt and libxml2 dependencies

Tags: xml, xslt, gtk, gnome, jhbuild

I am trying to compile via [jhbuild](http://developer.gnome.org/jhbuild/unstable/jhbuild-and-gnome.html.en) the yelp-xsl (The core XSLT stylesheets used by libyelp and [yelp](http://projects.gnome.org/yelp/)).

I am using Ubuntu Raring 13.04 fully updated from today.

I have [all the dependencies](https://live.gnome.org/JhbuildDependencies/) recommended [for Ubuntu](https://live.gnome.org/JhbuildDependencies/Ubuntu) installed and related development packages too:

```
$ dpkg -l libxslt* | grep dev; dpkg -l libxml2* | grep dev
un  libxslt-dev                                   <none>                                                       (no description available)
ii  libxslt1-dev                                  1.1.27-1ubuntu1                                 i386         XSLT 1.0 processing library - development kit
ii  libxml2-dev:i386                              2.9.0+dfsg1-4ubuntu1                            i386         Development files for the GNOME XML library
```

But running the compilation I get a failed result:

```
$ jhbuild build yelp-xsl
*** Verificando itstool *** [1/2]
*** Omitiendo itstool (paquete y dependencias no actualizados) *** [1/2]
*** Verificando yelp-xsl *** [2/2]
git remote set-url origin git://git.gnome.org/yelp-xsl
git remote update origin
Fetching origin
git pull --rebase
Current branch master is up to date.
*** Configurando yelp-xsl *** [2/2]
./autogen.sh --prefix /opt/gnome --libdir '/opt/gnome/lib'  --disable-static --disable-gtk-doc
autoreconf: Entering directory `.'
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gettext
autoreconf: running: aclocal --force -I m4 ${ACLOCAL_FLAGS}
autoreconf: configure.ac: tracing
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Libtool
autoreconf: running: /opt/gnome/bin/autoconf --force
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Autoheader
autoreconf: running: automake --add-missing --copy --force-missing
doc/yelp-xsl/Makefile.am:12: filter-out %db2html-suppressed.xsl,                        \
doc/yelp-xsl/Makefile.am:12:    $(sort $(patsubst ./%, %,                                       \
doc/yelp-xsl/Makefile.am:12:      $(foreach dir,$(xsldoc_dirs: non-POSIX variable name
doc/yelp-xsl/Makefile.am:12: (probably a GNU make extension)
doc/yelp-xsl/Makefile.am:12: wildcard $(dir: non-POSIX variable name
doc/yelp-xsl/Makefile.am:12: (probably a GNU make extension)
doc/yelp-xsl/Makefile.am:15: sort $(foreach xsl,$(xsldoc_xsls: non-POSIX variable name
doc/yelp-xsl/Makefile.am:15: (probably a GNU make extension)
doc/yelp-xsl/Makefile.am:15: basename $(notdir $(xsl: non-POSIX variable name
doc/yelp-xsl/Makefile.am:15: (probably a GNU make extension)
doc/yelp-xsl/Makefile.am:16: patsubst %, C/%.page, $(xsldoc_base: non-POSIX variable name
doc/yelp-xsl/Makefile.am:16: (probably a GNU make extension)
doc/yelp-xsl/Makefile.am:24: filter %/$(basename $(notdir $@: non-POSIX variable name
doc/yelp-xsl/Makefile.am:24: (probably a GNU make extension)
doc/yelp-xsl/Makefile.am:36: wildcard C/*.page: non-POSIX variable name
doc/yelp-xsl/Makefile.am:36: (probably a GNU make extension)
xslt/docbook/html/Makefile.am:30: wildcard db*.xsl: non-POSIX variable name
xslt/docbook/html/Makefile.am:30: (probably a GNU make extension)
autoreconf: Leaving directory `.'
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --disable-static, --disable-gtk-doc
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /home/shakaran/.local/bin/install-check
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for gawk... (cached) gawk
checking for itstool... itstool
checking for pkg-config... /opt/gnome/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for YELP_XSL... no
configure: error: Package requirements (
        libxml-2.0 >= 2.6.12
        libxslt    >= 1.1.8
) were not met:

No package 'libxml-2.0' found
No package 'libxslt' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables YELP_XSL_CFLAGS
and YELP_XSL_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
*** Error durante la fase configure de yelp-xsl: ########## Error de ejecución ./autogen.sh --prefix /opt/gnome --libdir '/opt/gnome/lib'  --disable-static --disable-gtk-doc  *** [2/2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asking in *#gnome-hackers* at irc.gnome.org. Some people tell me that the error was produced by use previously *jhbuild bootstrap*. This can create conflicts because there are a chance of a own pkg-config is installed, that it doesn't know about the multiarch ubuntu directories.

So running:

```
$ pkg-config --modversion libxml-2.0 libxslt
```

Reports *2.9.0* and *1.1.27* versions, but running:

```
$ jhbuild run pkg-config --modversion libxml-2.0 libxslt
Package libxml-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libxml-2.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libxml-2.0' found
Package libxslt was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libxslt.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libxslt' found
```

The only solution for fix this problem is wipe fully the */opt/gnome/* folder and try again. Then all work fine.

Comment: Another nasty solution is remove /opt/gnome/bin/pkg-config so jhbuild will use default system pkg-config. It works on ubuntu 12.10

Answer (score 0):

May be it is because you did not have the developer's version of libxml2 and libxslt installed?

http://tara24.de/fix-configure-error-package-requirements-libxslt-met/

Try this:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev
```

to see if your problem is solved?