# How to install libraries on jhbuild?

Tags: linux, gnome, jhbuild

I want to start to use jhbuild. It creates an isolated system to compile unstable packages ant try them. But it's not clear to me how to add a missing library to it.

Steps:

```
$ sudo apt-get install jhbuild
$ mkdir -p /opt/gnome
$ chown `whoami`.`whoami` /opt/gnome
$ mkdir ~/checkout/gnome
$ jhbuild bootstrap

... all correct ...

$ jhbuild sysdeps --install

... problems ...

Required packages:
 Packages too old:
 (none)
No match with system package
 soundtouch (soundtouch-1.4.pc, required=0)
 libicu (icu-i18n.pc, required=4)
 libunistring
 yajl
 device-mapper
...
```

I read something about installing libicu [here](https://live.gnome.org/JhbuildDependencies/Ubuntu), but It do not explain where to checkout an how to compile.

I have tried

```
$ svn checkout http://source.icu-project.org/repos/icu/icu/tags/release-4-8/
$ cd release-4-8/source
$ ./autogen.sh --prefix=/opt/gnome
$ make
$ make install
```

with no luck.

My system is a 64bits one. I say because I have made [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14933206/848072) hack already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a 64bit system and jhbuild is installing into /opt/gnome then you need to set your libdir to install libraries into /opt/gnome/lib64

add `--libdir=/opt/gnome/lib64` onto the autogen.sh line.

Answer (score 1):

You can just run sudo-apt get install libicu. The sysdeps are system dependencies, so they don't need to be installed in the JHBuild checkout, just on your system.

You might find this wiki page helpful: https://wiki.gnome.org/HowDoI/Jhbuild